# naming a list when returning values from data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table

When returning items to `data.table`, it would be nice if they automatically took on the names of the variables.  How does one do this? This is what I mean:

```
require(data.table)
x = data.table(a=1:10, id=1:2)
x[,{s = sum(a); p=prod(a); y = sqrt(abs(s*p)); z = y+1; list(y, z)},by=id]

#   id V1   V2
#1:  1 25  945
#2:  2 30 3840
```

Instead of `V1` and `V2` it would be nice if the columsn were labeled `s` and `p`. It's no big thing to do this here but if you have 20 columns it becomes a real pain. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: I changed the question to make clear why I don't just do list(name = value)

Comment: oh yeh looks to be related. i guess that FR is still open? is there a way to do this more succinctly in R then to do `list(x=x, y=y, z=z)`. i understand it's not a `data.table` thing but what is the quickest way to generate this expression in R instead of doing it by hand?

Comment: Hrm, it looks like @GSee dropped that comment with the [link](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2286&group_id=240&atid=978). Anyway, I'm also curious about this.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the comment because I think that is a different feature request.

Comment: As @Justin and others have mentioned, the solution is simply to name the elements of the list. This is `base R` stuff and not much to do with `data.table`. That being said, I could certainly see benefit to to automating the name. However, I perceive a lot of pitfalls and corner cases. What would a dependable solution look like?  by dependable I mean "predicatable in all cases". Currently, one can implement `DT[, list(mean(x), sd(x))]$V1` and know with certainty that this will return `mean(x)`.  If there are corner cases, the certainty is sacrificed.

Comment: It sounds like the OP just wants to return a list without the names and have it assign names based on variables, but that isn't how R works... However, `data.table` does, so as I mentioned in my answer, one could substitute `data.table` for `list` in the above code and have a named result...

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Yeah, so maybe there could be an option for this sort of thing, `dt[,list(...),makeNames=TRUE]`.

Comment: @Frank, yep, my question is really this:  What should the names be?  Let's say there are 5 functions, and 4 of them are of a single variable, but the 5th is a function of two variables.  What do we name that fifth variable (assume the DT has many more cols than just 5)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I was just thinking it would mimic the behavior of `data.frame()` and `data.table()` when they receive unnamed arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm missing something... but isn't the standard `list` syntax for `data.table` what you're looking for?  It is more concise and clearer IMHO.

```
x[, 
  list(s = sum(a),
       p = prod(a)),
  by=id] 

#    id  s    p
# 1:  1 25  945
# 2:  2 30 3840
```

You can also build up this `list` as an `expression` and `eval` it.

```
foo <- expression(list(s=sum(a), p=prod(a)))

x[, eval(foo), by=id]
```

This can then be extended to a function (using `as.quoted` from `plyr` instead cause its handy):

```
expression_maker <- function(funs, cols, names) {
   require(plyr)
   list_contents <- paste0(names, '=', funs, '(', cols, ')', collapse=',')
   as.quoted(paste('list(', list_contents, ')'))[[1]]
}

output <- expression_maker(funs=c('sum', 'prod'), cols=c('a', 'a'), names=c('s', 'p'))
x[, eval(output), by=id]
```

... But there be dragons!

---

per OP's edit:

```
x[,{s = sum(a); p=prod(a); y = sqrt(abs(s*p)); z = y+1; list(y, z)},by=id]
```

I would do this in a function and return a `data.table` directly:

```
yourfun <- function(a) {
  s <- sum(a)
  p <- prod(a)
  y <- sqrt(abs(s*p))
  z <- y+1
  data.table(y, z)
}

x[, yourfun(a), by=id]
```

Comment: Putting them in separate list items may be inefficient if they take info from the same source, e.g., `x[,{mylm<-lm(a~id);data.frame(mylm$fitted.values,mylm$residuals)}]`. Maybe that's a bit contrived, but I think there are uses.

Comment: @Justin: this is just a very simple example. in my real code i have a complicated epxression being evaluated which takes on intermediate values. at the end i return a final result.

Comment: Still not sure I follow.  If you're looking for fewest characters, my list version looses by a few equals signs.  If you're running complex functions and things, why not just take the trivial step of `setnames` after or alter your functions to return named data.tables themselves?  @Alex see my edit

Answer (score 2):

A remix of the other two answers - name them in the list:

```
x[,{s = sum(a); p=prod(a); y = sqrt(abs(s*p)); z = y+1;
    list(s = y, p = z)}, by=id]
```

or construct a `data.table`

```
x[,{s = sum(a); p=prod(a); y = sqrt(abs(s*p)); z = y+1;
    data.table(y, z)}, by=id]
```

And here's another option using `Hmisc` (this is slower than naming manually, but probably faster than `data.table`):

```
library(Hmisc)
x[,{s = sum(a); p=prod(a); y = sqrt(abs(s*p)); z = y+1;
    llist(y, z)}, by=id]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a large amount of vairables and you are looking for a programmatic way to approach this, you can put the names of the columns in a vector and then use `sapply` with `.SDcols`
eg:

```
## sample data
set.seed(7)
DT <- as.data.table(matrix(round(runif(130, 1, 100)), ncol=26))
setnames(DT, LETTERS)


## These are the columns we will compute on
Cols <- c("A", "G", "M", "W", "Z")

DT[,sapply(.SD,mean),.SDcols=Cols]

#    A    G    M    W    Z 
# 25.0 41.2 55.6 43.0 56.0
```

If you want to compute different functions on each variable, then use the standard `list(nm=function(x))`

Comment: I guess you mean `DT[,sapply(.SD,mean),.SDcols=Cols]`? That's what I've seen a lot on SO, anyway.

Comment: Oh, this result is not a `data.table` any more, which is why the naming works out, right?

Comment: Messy fix: `DT[,c(mean=as.list(sapply(.SD,mean))),.SDcols=Cols]`. @ comment below: Oh, right.

Comment: that's not neccessary.  just use `lapply` instead.